# Interaction of solid objects and change of trajectory

Tags: classical-mechanics, kinematics, solid-state-physics

I have two solid objects. Each of them has an arbitary complex surface, which is discribed by set of vertices. The aim is to describe their interaction, result of which is the change in trajectory of one of them.

Example: one object (M1) is stable and fixed. The second object (M2) moves along some certain axis and has, for example, one degree of freedom perpindicular to the motion axis. In some moment M2 touches M1. Because of the degree of freedom, M2 changes its trajectory from line to some curve, the form of which depends on the form of two interacted objects.

So, how it can be described in formulas? Of course, there can be up to 6 degrees of freedom.

Comment: I don't understand your "M2 has one degree of freedom". Basically, you have 12 degrees of freedom, and some equations for linear and angular momentum. What you miss here is a description of the interaction force during collission.

Comment: @Bernhard I meant, if M2 moves along X-axis, it can change its trajectory only in XY-plane, but without changing direction relatively to X-axis.

Comment: @Bernhard About 12 degrees of freedom - it's debatable matter. Properly each simple object in N-dimesional space has N*(N-1)/2 degrees of freedom, so in our 3-d space - 6 ones.

Comment: But you have two objects.

Comment: @Bernhard M1 is fixed.

Comment: Also after the collision? Then really the force  can be anything...

Comment: @Bernhard Yes. M1 is fixed, and M2 "moves with contact around" M1. Really, I only need to know the path of this "movement" depending on available amount of degrees of freedom.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a very arbitrary question. It would be much easier if you could just elaborate on one given "specific" and well defined scenario, that you wish to solve, then one can help. From which then you would analogously try to solve other similar scenarios.

From what you've asked thus far, your starting point should be Conservation of momentum. Since in the interactions, you're not assuming any loss of mass(explosion of the objects), then define the momentum of each object, $\vec{p}=m\vec{v}$ before the collision and after the collision, then you have your first equation: $$\sum_{i=1}^n m_n \vec{v}_n = \sum_{i=1}^n m'_n \vec{v'}_n$$

The prime symbol is to distinguish between before/after collisions and the sum goes over n objects. Furthermore, if the collisions are elastic (as opposed to inelastic ones where heat is created), then kinetic energy is also conserved, then you have a second equation to work with, and of course if the objects are also free to rotate, then the angular momentum conservation equation has to be established (here assuming that it is, doesn't have to be): $$\sum_{i=1}^n J_n \vec{\omega}_n = \sum_{i=1}^n J'_n \vec{\omega'}_n$$
Where $\omega$ is the angular velocity, and $J$ the moment of inertia, which in your case, if you're not dealing with known geometric objects, then defining the correct $J$ will be a very cumbersome task, as it boils down to solving: $$J = \int_0^M r^2 dm$$
Which describes how the total mass of an object is distributed with respect to its center of mass. To solve the integral, each case is specific, e.g. for a cylinder, one usually sums shells of cylinders, to solve $J$.

Comment: Somehow, in my first three readings of your 3rd paragraph, I skipped over 'prime' and was confused as to where the sign was.

Comment: hehe sorry, replaced "sign" with the word symbol to prevent any further confusion for our future visitors. :)